# After changing my $PATH on Mac, how can I change it back?

Tags: bash, macos

I tried to change my $PATH on my Mac computer.
I tried to add a line at the end of the .bash_profile:

```
export $PATH=${PATH}:$"/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin"$
```

After that, I executed `source ./.bash_profile`, and the `$PATH` has changed.
When I change the file back by deleting that export line, saving it, and then executed `source ./.bash_profile`, the `$PATH` is changed and it does not change back.

Comment: Your .bash_profile contained instructions to add that directory to `PATH`. Removing that instruction and running it again doesn't do anything to *remove* it, it just doesn't add it again.

Comment: @Jerry : Why do you think the `PATH` should mysteriously change back by itself, after you have modified it?

Comment: Ok how can I remove the part of $PATH then

Comment: Like now my echo $PATH is completely different from my previous echo $PATH

Comment: try it written as `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Cmake.app/Contents/bin`

Comment: @RichardBarber But can I change the $PATH back?

Comment: @Jerry Open a new Terminal window. It’ll run the setup process again *from scratch*, so you’ll get a clean new environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recombining the envvar `PATH` when you run it again. You'll likely have to restart your shell after making the change.